# $K_1$ of Categories for intuition

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Maybe there is no good answer to this, but I'm trying to get a feel for what the $K$-theory of a (permutative or symmetric monoidal $\infty$-)category computes.

In algebraic $K$-theory, we have explicit descriptions for the low $K$-groups, where $K_0(R)$ is the Grothendieck group of finite projective modules and $K_1(R)$ is the abelianization of $\text{Gl}(R)$ (the infinite general linear group) so for commutative rings we compute the units of the ring.

The $K$-theory of $\mathrm{Proj}_R$ recovers $K(R)$, and the description of $K_0$ translates to the categorical generalization, that is $K_0(\mathcal{C})$ is the Grothendieck group of $\mathcal{C}$. However I could not find an analogue of $K_1(\mathcal{C})$, so to speak what are the units of a category? Maybe the automorphisms of the unit object?

Comment: You can find this in Def. 3.1.6 of Rosenberg’s K-theory book for categories with exact sequences

Comment: For categories with exact sequences you look at pairs consisting of an object and an automorphism of that object. You have relations that tell you that composition of automorphisms correspond to sum and things add over exact sequences if the correct diagrams commute.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg the question is about permutative and symmetric monoidal categories. That’s a different kind of beast.

Comment: @FernandoMuro, it’s not clear the question is about that.  The op says they are trying to get a feel for k-theory of these things but then turns to algebraic k-theory and doesn’t seem to know how one recovers K1 in a categorical way in that context. I felt the op wanted to understand in this context to then generalize to the other setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an exact category ${\cal N}$, Dan Grayson (who occasionally shows up on MathOverflow) gave explicit generators and relations for $K_n$ [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2012-25-04/S0894-0347-2012-00743-7/S0894-0347-2012-00743-7.pdf).

What follows is essentially quoted directly from that paper except that I've done some minor edits to make it self-contained:

> **Definition.** An *acyclic binary multicomplex of dimension $n$* in ${\cal N}$ is a bounded ${\mathbb Z}^n$-graded object of ${\cal N}$ equipped with acyclic differentials $d_i$ and $d_i'$ in direction $i$, for each $i$ with $1 \le i \le n$, where the maps $d_i$ and $d_i'$ commute with $d_j$ and $d_j'$ provided $i \neq j$. (Four pairs of maps have just been asserted to commute: $d_i$ commutes with $d_j$ , $d_i$ commutes with $d_j'$ , $d_i'$ commutes with $d_j$, and $d_i'$ commutes with $d_j'$.)
>
> A map between acyclic binary multicomplexes is a map of underlying graded objects that commutes with each of the differentials, and a short exact sequence is a short sequence consisting of short exact sequences in each component.
>
> **Theorem.** If ${\cal N}$ is an exact category, then the abelian group $K_n({\cal N})$ has the following presentation by generators and relations:
>
> There is one generator for each acyclic binary multicomplex of dimension $n$ in ${\cal N}$ .
>
> The relations are of two types:
>
> (1) those coming from short exact sequences, as in the definition of the Grothendieck group;
>
> (2) any generator that is trivial, in the sense that $d_i = d_i'$ for some $i$, is made to vanish.

In particular, the generators for $K_1$ are *a priori* ${\mathbb Z}$-indexed sequences of objects equipped with two acyclic differentials.  But from earlier work of Nenashev, we can restrict to a smaller group of generators, namely the *doubly exact sequences* in which all but three successive objects vanish.  That is, a generator is a pair of short exact sequences having the same objects in all three non-zero locations.  (This applies only to $K_1$, not to higher $K_n$.)